# How do I compare a value to the value in a csv file?

Tags: python

I have a csv file, in the format:

```
text, class
text0,class0
text1,class1
..., ...
```

Im importing the file, and putting the columns into lists with:

```
textt=data['text']
classs=data['class']
```

I then run a script that classifies each piece of text into two categories.

```
for i in textt:
    #classify text
    text_class=#guessed_text_class
```

I want to compare the text_class to the class of each row, and do:

```
if text_class==class:
    print('correct')
```

edit: example:
csv file looks like this:

```
text, class
'I hate Billy', 'Joe'
'I love Joe', 'Joe'
'I love Billy', 'Billy'
```

file is imported with:

```
with open('csv_file', 'rU') as infile:
reader=csv.DictReader(infile)
data={}
for row in reader:
    for header, value in row.items():
        try:
            data[header].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            data[header]=[value]
```

textt=data['Text']
classes=data['Class']

each sentence in the 'text' column is classified:

```
for i in textt:
    #classifies text
    text_class=#guessed text class
```

my attempt at finding if the text_class is correct is:

```
for i in range(len(textt))
    if i=text_class:
        print('correct')
```

However, this ends comparing the last classes item in the list, in this case 'Billy', to the classes items. So it would end up looking like:

the guessed classes would be:
    'Joe'
    'Joe'
    'Billy'

but instead of comparing:

```
'Joe'=='Joe'
'Joe'=='Joe'
'Billy'=='Billy'
```

it would compare:

```
'Billy'=='Joe'
'Billy'=='Joe'
'Billy'=='Billy'
```

Comment: Nice explanation but what is your question? Do you wonder about the `SyntaxError` that the last part raises? It would be easier to answer if you provided a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My question is how do I get from the 'text_class=#guessed_text_class' to the 'if text_class==class: print("correct")'. The way I tried to do it was after the 'for i in textt' part, write another for loop: 'for i in range(x): if text_class==class: print("correct")', but this would just compare it to the text_class of the last item in textt

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you are asking. Please add some sample data for `textt` and `classs` together with as much *running* code as you can come up with, plus some sample output that you want to obtain. And if you don't mind you could rename your variables to something more readable such as `text` and `classes`.

Comment: Looks like you would have to share your `guess` function, along with some test cases as well.

Comment: i added an edit, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean to accomplish?

```
for txt, cls in zip(textt, classs):
     if txt==cls: 
        print('correct')
```

Comment: yes, but that didnt print anything, and when I added an `else: print('wrong')` statement, it printed everything as wrong

Comment: this did end up working, i misunderstood where I should have started the for loop. Thanks

Comment: No problem - happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `enumerate` function you can check your result at the same iteration, assumed you have the same order in both lists.

```
for counter,i in enumerate(textt):
    #classify text
    text_class=#guessed_text_class
    if text_class == classs[counter]:
        print('correct')
```

Comment: I get the error: `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Is textt a list or a single string?

Comment: sry, I screwed up  a bit on the logic part. text_class needs no counter, just classs does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lists have the same length, and are correctly ordered, then you can simply run a loop from `0` to `length-1`, and compare your classes.

```
for i in range(len(classs)):
    if text_class == classs[i]:
        print("yes")
```

In your case, I assume you would want to guess the class and then compare it within the same loop. So you can use the below implementation.

```
for i in range(len(classs)): # or len(textt). Since, I assume both would be same
    text_class = guess(textt[i])
    if text_class == classs[i]:
        print("yes")
```

Comment: would that still work if when im guessing the class, i start the for loop with `for i in textt`? how would I start the for loop to use both lists?